# How to create a responsive scrollable table?

Tags: html, css, html-table, media-queries

I tried with this for create a scrollable table, for a responsive design. But not working. If this is not possible, how I do?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
table {
    overflow-x: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
}
```

The HTML code:

```
<table>
    <tr class="col">
          <td id="col-1">
               Servidor
          </td>
          <td id="col-2">
               Calidad
          </td>
          <td id="col-3">
               Idioma
          </td>
          <td id="col-4">
               Enlace
          </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

The CSS code:

```
#movie-links #links-info tr {margin: 0;}
#movie-links #links-info .col {background: #F1F1F1; border-bottom: 1px solid #CACACA; float: left; color: gray; padding: 10px;}
#movie-links #links-info .col td {margin: 0;}
#movie-links #links-info #col-1 {width: 150px;}
#movie-links #links-info #col-2 {width: 200px;}
#movie-links #links-info #col-3 {width: 150px;}
#movie-links #links-info #col-4 {width: 300px;}
```

Comment: You have a list inside a table, with no rows or cells? This is invalid HTML, how did you expect this to work?

Comment: Edited. Sorry @LegoStormtroopr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need scroll horizontally use overflow-x:scroll
incase of vertical use overflow-y:scroll